# Python :AttributeError when I try to set a variable(Boolean)

Tags: python

I am trying to set the Boolean Variable "self.running" to True in order as a check to show that the application is running, and will refresh the canvas. However, whenever I run this code, I get back the error message:
"line 29, in mainloop
    if self.running == True:
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'running'"
 the actual code for this is simply

```
    self.running = True
```

I don't see the actual issue here, as I am a newbie to python and coding world in general, I searched around but found different scenarios then the one I had and couldn't apply their solutions to my issue. Thank you.

edit:Code

```
   class Game:
def _init_(self):
    self.tk = Tk()
    self.running = False
    self.tk.title("Man runs to door. Wins nobel prize.")
    self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
    self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
        highlightthickness=0)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.tk.update()
    self.canvas_height = 500
    self.canvas_width = 500
    self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
    w = self.bg.width()
    h = self.bg.height()
    for x in range(0, 5):
        for y in range(0, 5):
            self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
                image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
    self.sprites = []
    self.running = True

def mainloop(self):
    while 1:
        if self.running == True:
            for sprite in self.sprites:
                sprite.move()
        self.tk.update_idletasks()
        self.tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

this is the entire initialization area and mainloop.

would this be a correct version of the code then?

```
    class Game:
def _init_(self):
    self.tk = Tk()
    self.running = False
    self.tk.title("Man runs to door. Wins nobel prize.")
    self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
    self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
        highlightthickness=0)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.tk.update()
    self.canvas_height = 500
    self.canvas_width = 500
    self.bg = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
    w = self.bg.width()
    h = self.bg.height()
    for x in range(0, 5):
        for y in range(0, 5):
            self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
                image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
    self.sprites = []
    self.running = True

def mainloop(self):
    while 1:
        if self.running == True:
            for sprite in self.sprites:
                sprite.move()
        self.tk.update_idletasks()
        self.tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Please post more of the code: it seems that you have an object called `Game`. Most likely, you need to put `self.running = True` in your `__init__()` method.

Comment: `__init__` needs two underscores on each side. Also, in a language like Python, it's crucial that you format your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

From the updated question - your `mainloop` is not inside your `Game` class, so `self` doesn't work as you expect. You need to properly indent your code:

```
class Game
    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)

game = Game()
game.mainloop()
```

Ensure that `mainloop` is indented 4 spaces inside of `Game`.

Comment: Please post your constructor in the question. Are you sure it's properly indented and inside of the `Game` class?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the spacing but I know it is how you put it in the example,

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might have a class called Game in your code and you just miss the "self.running" in the initialization:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
```

Comment: I did you're exact line of code, and it produced a spacing error, so I moved  it down, and it came up with the same error as before placing it into the init area

Answer (score 0):

This error message says your self.running has not been initialized.

I am not sure where do you assign `self.running = True`.

The best way to do is add this code into your `__init__` method

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on your `def __init__(self):`

Note that the `init` is surrounded by two underscores and not just one like your example code.

The rest looks fine, but it would be more pythonic to just write
`if self.running:`
instead of comparing it to `True`.

Also, be sure to check your identation as pointed out by Martin Konecny.